# Does an layout transition (image barrier) itself constitute a transfer write or read for access masks?

Tags: vulkan

If I place an image memory barrier with src stage transfer bit, means that the transfer stage of all previous commands will have been completed. If I place the src access mask as VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT that means all previous transfers will have been made available. Now I do an layout transition. Does the transition constitute a transfer operation or need to make memory visible?

In other words when the image is finished transitioning do I need to make the memory (that the image is in) visible for future commands that use that image?

Comment: "*means all previous transfers will have been made available*" All previous *write* transfer operations. "*Now I do an image transition*" Do you mean a "layout transition"?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, an image layout transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it did constitute a transfer write, the [specification](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-image-layout-transitions) would say so. When using the Vulkan API I suggest you do not leap to conclusions, and instead simply use this document yourself, which generally does say what and when happens.

Nevertheless a layout transition **is** considered a modifying memory access, and needs to be synchronized with previous and subsequent work as not to cause memory hazard.

Layout transition does **not** happen in any specific pipeline stage or with any specific access mask. It simply happens somewhere between the first and sceond synchronization scope of the Dependency which contains the transition. The availability-visibility operations of the layout transition itself are automatic:

> When a layout transition is specified in a memory dependency, it happens-after the availability operations in the memory dependency, and happens-before the visibility operations. Image layout transitions **may** perform read and write accesses on all memory bound to the image subresource range, so applications **must** ensure that all memory writes have been made available before a layout transition is executed. Available memory is automatically made visible to a layout transition, and writes performed by a layout transition are automatically made available.

Comment: "Available memory is automatically made visible to a layout transition,", so you transfer to an image, you don't need src access mask TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT in the image barrier/transition? I guess it doesn't hurt though, or does it? Does that mean it'll flush memory twice?

Comment: @Zebrafish You have to sequence lauout transition after any previous accesses and before any subsequent accesses. The previous accesses must be made available-from. They bacome automatically visible-to the layout transition and subsequently automatically available-from the layout transition and then must manually be made visible-to subsequent access. No access mask whatsoever is applicable here; as stated, layout transition does **not** happen in any specific stage or with **no** specific access type offered by `VkAccessFlagBits`. Extraneous parameters passed to Vulkan may degrate performance.